# Drawer Menu (hamburger) icon visibility, no background?

Tags: android, hamburger, visibility

Looking for some input on this. So usually, in an Android app, you have a single colored toolbar at the top with the hamburger icon on the left. We've opted to make that toolbar transparent, and allow content to be seen under it, which provides some more vertical screen space and looks pretty neat. The issue is, the menu icon is sometimes hard to see depending on the content behind it at the time. We've looked at some options but currently we've added a very slight gradient scrim to the top of the app, which helps with the menu icons visibility immensely.

The scrim does cause the content of the app at the top to appear to have a slight shadow on top of it though, so I was wondering if any of you had any other ideas on how to increase the visibility of the menu icon without using the gradient scrim.

Comment: It would help your question if you were to include some images.

Comment: Maybe you can put circle as the icon background or even you can just remove the bar with icon on circle

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky issue. You could add a slight drop shadow to your menu icon.

[image]

If making the toolbar transparent is so important, you might want to consider doing some image sampling and inverse the background color of the toolbar. For example light background image -> black transparent toolbar, vice versa. Although I'm not sure how you can achieve that in an android app.

Comment: To add to what Adamso said, you could also give the icon a thin black outline, or put it in front of a transparent bar.

Comment: Yea the content behind the icon is dynamic. There is a way to sample the color behind it and set the icon accordingly so it stands out, but with dynamic content that scrolls it would be tricky.

Comment: Alternatively you could place a round dark banner behind the menu icon. https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/363140/burger_circle_circular_grid_hamburger_interface_items_layout_list_menu_round_stack_web_icon